# SmartContract for more Whitelistings

Tags: solidity, remix, smart-contract-wallets

Can you please explain to me if I have the right structure? I probably don't have it when it doesn't work for me, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I need to create a smartcontract in which I will keep a list of several projects, and each project will have its own list of users.

I've tried to do it in different ways, but I always have an error message that I can't handle. So I'd like to know first if I'm stu-pid or i-diot.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Test {

    struct Project {
        uint id;
        string name;
        //I want to have a separate list of users for each project BUT
        Whitelist[] addressList; //return: UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Test.Whitelist memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.
        //Whitelist addressList; //return different error msg, but is not array :-(
    }

    // I want more projects 
    Project[] public projects;

    struct Whitelist {
        uint signupDate;
        address userAddress;
    }
    
    Whitelist[] public whitelists;

    function createProject(uint projectId, string memory projectName) public 
    {
        // This is only here because I don't know how to create and assign an empty array.
         Whitelist memory newWhitelist = Whitelist ({
                signupDate: block.timestamp,
                userAddress: msg.sender
            });
        
        whitelists.push(newWhitelist);

        Project memory newProject = Project ({
            id: projectId,
            name: projectName,
            // Array still doesn't want to assign me. I don't know how to edit it
            addressList: whitelists
        });

        projects.push(newProject);
    }

     function getProjects() public view returns (Project[] memory) {
      //  I don't even know what different experiment worked with me, but this will return the list of projects to me with the right list of users?
      return projects;
    }

    function getProjectUsers(uint projectId) public view returns (Whitelist[] memory) {
      return projects[projectId].addressList;
    }

}
```

My questions:
Is the structure design correct?
How do I create a project with an empty user list? So that I don't have to save the admin account there.
How do I add users to a specific list? I have a feeling this has not worked in any attempt:

```
projects[projectId].addressList.push(newUser);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your overall code is too complex, I did some modifications:

1. I removed the struct Project, it's now a `string[]` where the `index` is the `projectId`
2. I mapped the id to an array of `Whitelist`
3. I added a few events so you can track all the new whitelists, and retrieve them easily from your frontend for example
4. Added a function `whitelistUsers` to whitelist users for to a specific `projectId`, it takes an array of `address` and `signupDate` is the moment this function is called
5. changed the visibility of the functions from `public` to `external` since there is no need to make them public since you're not calling them anywhere in your code (it will saves gas)

   ```
   // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
   pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

   contract Test {
       event ProjectCreated(uint id, string name);
       event UserWhitelisted(uint indexed id, address user, uint signupDate);



       struct Whitelist {
           uint signupDate;
           address userAddress;
       }

       //array of string where the index is the id, e.g projects[0] is "ABC"
       string[] public projects;

       //We use the indexes of the projects to set the whitelist, each id(index or project) has a whitelist
       mapping(uint => Whitelist[]) projectsWhitelist;


       // Push the name to the array of string and emit an event
       function createProject(string calldata projectName) external {
           projects.push(projectName);

           emit ProjectCreated(projects.length - 1, projectName);
       }

       function whitelistUsers(uint projectId, address[] calldata users) external {
           for (uint i; i < users.length; i++) {
               projectsWhitelist[projectId].push(
                   Whitelist({
                       userAddress: users[i],
                       signupDate: block.timestamp
                   })
               );
               emit UserWhitelisted(projectId, users[i], block.timestamp);
           }
       }

       function getProjects() external view returns (string[] memory) {
           return projects;
       }

       function getProjectUsers(uint projectId)
           external
           view
           returns (Whitelist[] memory)
       {
           return projectsWhitelist[projectId];
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for editing the code, as well as for the comments. It helped me a lot. Thank you very much again. Where can I buy you coffee? ;-)

Comment: my pleasure! haha, thanks no need :)